# WiX Installer Spawn an Executable

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

My questions is simply this, I have a WiX installer .msi that I want to be able to, after successful installation, an executable that runs another installation.  Now the reason I need to do this is that the WiX installer installs an application that was developed recently and the executable that I need to run installs another application that was developed a long time ago.  The second executable is fully independent from the first installation and does not have to be uninstalled when the application installed by the .MSI is is so I do not have to worry about roll backs.  I was wondering if there is a way to have the .msi use a CA that will launch the .exe upon completion?  I know how to get the .msi to launch the application it installs itself after installation but the executable I need is not included in the .msi, which is where my confusion/deleama is coming from.  So if anyone could maybe point me in the right direction that would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the typical case for an installer chainer, particularly since the installers are independent. WiX offers a [Bootstrapper](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm) project type that creates a bootstrapper/downloader/chainer. It would be ideal for your situation.

You can create such a project using the Bootstrapper project template in Visual Studio or by writing the needed XML files by hand. By default, the bootstrapper creates an uninstall entry for itself to be uninstalled and it will uninstall all of its packages. But, if you prefer, you can make the ExePackage permanent (with respect to the bootstrapper).

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer because this will do exactly was it is I am trying to do but I am having an issue building my bootstrapper project and am not sure I should post a new question or if I can just ask it here.  Thank you for the link and the advice!

Comment: You should as a new question so it won't complicate this one and you'll get the benefit of others looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Tom Blodget, Wix Bootstrapper is the best option for your case.

If you don’t want to go with that option then try [Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Install the msi from Inno setup and you can do many things with inno setup like preinstall or post install, etc.